# How can I link customer_id with product_id that he ordered?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales

I know there are two tables `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_item`

but the relevant fields in `sales_flat_order` are:

`customer_id, base_total_paid` etc but no relation to product

and in the other table

`order_id, product_id`, but no relation to customer.

So I cant see any common field to link them.

I am trying to export 2 tables so that I can create a new database from scratch not based in magento, and I need  to know what each customer ordered.

Something like this:

```
select product_id, customer_id
from cp8_sales_flat_order
left join cp8_sales_flat_order_item
on sales_flat_order_item.order_id = sales_flat_oder.entity_id
```

I am getting an error that #1054 - Unknown column 'sales_flat_order_item.order_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sales_flat_order` table `entity_id` is the **primary key** and you can use that to get all items in an order

Columns to look in your case

**Table: sales_flat_order**

```
+------------------+
| Field            |
+------------------+
| entity_id  (PK)  |
| customer_id      |
| base_total_paid  |
+------------------+
```

**Table: sales_flat_order_item**

```
+------------------+
| Field            |
+------------------+
| item_id  (PK)    |
| order_id (FK)    |
| product_id       |
+------------------+
```

so you need to filter orders with selected customer id from sales_flat_order then using `entity_id` you need join sales_order_item `order_id`.

Comment: a query like the one I have just written? I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get product details from order. First get order placed by customer and then from that order id you can get ordered products in magento.